# Unable to start activity in android...?

Tags: android, global-variables, start-activity

As i am new to android development i am struck up with a problem in my project. Code is..

for processing webservice code i am calling webinterface class from main.java file as follows.

Main.java

```
      @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
WebServiceInterface webinterface=   new WebServiceInterface();
submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getuser = username.getText().toString();
            getpass = password.getText().toString();

            HashMap<String, Object> map =  new HashMap<String,Object>();
            map.put("username", getuser);
            map.put("password", getpass);
            webinterface.sendRequest(map);
        }
    });
```

In Webinterface class i am receiving the following map values & converting them to string & send to RestClient.class to process webservice request..

WebServiceInterface.java

```
    ArrayList<String> ast = new ArrayList<String>();
  Collection<Object> strings = map.values();
    Iterator iterator = strings.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        getuser = (String) iterator.next();
        ast.add(getuser);
    }

    String password = ast.get(0).toString();
    String username = ast.get(1).toString();

    RestClient client = new RestClient(
            "***********************");
    client.AddParam("username", username);
    client.AddParam("password", password);

    try {
        client.Execute(RequestMethod.POST);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

      String response = client.getResponse();

     /** here getting response & sending that response back to Main.java class**/

       Main main = new Main();
   main.responseData(responsedata);
```

here after receiving response method from interface class the following process is going on in Main.java class

Main.java

```
     @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      System.out.println("response is----^^^^^^^^^^====>>>>>>    " + getrespstatus + "_______---->>   > " + respdoctorID);
       }//end of oncreate...

  public void responseData(HashMap<String, Object> responsedata) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("response data in main class->>>>>>>>  "  + responsedata);

    Collection<Object> strings = responsedata.values();
    Iterator iterator = strings.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        getresponse = (String) iterator.next();
        ast.add(getresponse);
    }

    String status = ast.get(0).toString();

    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(status);
        getrespstatus = json.getString("status");
        respdoctorID = json.getString("doctorID");
        callmethod(getrespstatus, respdoctorID);
        System.out.println("response is----^^^^^^^^^^====>>>>>>    " + getrespstatus + "_______---->>   > " + respdoctorID);
                /* if(getrespstatus == "true")
                  {
                   startActivity(new Intent(Main.this,Second.class)) 
                  }else 
                  {
                    //some alert message
                   }*/
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

here if response status== true, i want to start activity. but here i am getting error as null pointer exception.. 
And my other doubt is here i am getting response & doctorID. if i am trying to access the following values in oncreate method, it showing as null values (simply to say if i am printing response values in log, in responseData method i am getting, if printing from oncreate getting null values) So, can anyone help me with this...

Comment: Your code seems vague. You need to understand about the `Activity` and its life cycle.

Comment: And you dont need to do this: `Main main = new Main();`. I mean no need to implement method like sending and receiving response as such.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `super` in `onCreate`. I strongly recommend reading [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) about Activity lifecycle.

As for returning the response, the simplest way would be to add your Main instance to the WebInterface class as a reference, maybe in constructor.

Comment: Thanks for you answer..  can you provide any example related to my code.....

Comment: Add this line to onCreate():
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: @MártonMolnár, I think he hasnt post all his code. where is the setcontview()

Comment: i already added the following line